# How to pipe pg_recvlogical to psql for logical replication?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to migrate from AWS Aurora to RDS. I've figured out how to do table replication and now I'm trying to figure out how to perform logical replication so that I can mirror changes on the source db to the destination db while I perform the application cutover.

I can successfully make a logical replication slot on the source db with

```
SELECT pg_create_logical_replication_slot('migration_goldsky', 'wal2json');
```

And then I can successfully consume those changes with `pg_recvlogical`:

```
ubuntu@ip-192-168-170-204:~$ pg_recvlogical --start -d "postgresql://root:<redacted>@graph-node-db.cluster-cpyibfvmddkk.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com/goldsky" --slot migration_goldsky --start --verbose --plugin=wal2json -f -
pg_recvlogical: starting log streaming at 0/0 (slot migration_goldsky)
pg_recvlogical: streaming initiated
pg_recvlogical: confirming write up to 0/0, flush to 0/0 (slot migration_goldsky)
{"change":[{"kind":"delete","schema":"goldsky_api","table":"Webhook","oldkeys":{"keynames":["id"],"keytypes":["text"],"keyvalues":["webhook_clffq1h380ewq3ss5herxdwp0"]}}]}
pg_recvlogical: confirming write up to 796/3D34378, flush to 796/3D34378 (slot migration_goldsky)
{"change":[{"kind":"insert","schema":"goldsky_api","table":"Webhook","columnnames":["id","name","project_id","subgraph_deployment_id","created_at"],"columntypes":["text","text","text","text","timestamp(6) with time zone"],"columnvalues":["webhook_clffq45rf0eyj3ss5c1hjezo8","main","project_cl6whd3a6000k0ixjfp9t9at5","sgd_cle4aoyna00o63svl90yf1h9z","2023-03-19 18:20:37.806+00"]}]}
pg_recvlogical: confirming write up to 796/3EB9BA0, flush to 796/3EB9BA0 (slot migration_goldsky)
```

However, I can't figure out how to get psql to apply those changes to the destination database. I've tried using unix pipes to pipe the `pg_recvlogical` output directly to `psql` like so, but it didn't work:

```
 pg_recvlogical --start -d "postgresql://root:<redacted>@graph-node-db.cluster-cpyibfvmddkk.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com/goldsky" --slot migration_goldsky --start --verbose -f - | psql "postgresql://root:<redacted>@graph-node-db-2.cpyibfvmddkk.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com/goldsky" -a -b -e
```

I've tried saving the changes to a text file and then piping that to `psql` like so (this also didn't work):

```
ubuntu@ip-192-168-170-204:~$ pg_recvlogical --start -d "postgresql://root:<redacted>@graph-node-db.cluster-cpyibfvmddkk.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com/goldsky" --slot migration_goldsky --start --verbose --plugin=wal2json -f change.txt
pg_recvlogical: starting log streaming at 0/0 (slot migration_goldsky)
pg_recvlogical: streaming initiated
pg_recvlogical: confirming write up to 0/0, flush to 0/0 (slot migration_goldsky)
pg_recvlogical: confirming write up to 796/12EEA0D8, flush to 796/12EEA0D8 (slot migration_goldsky)
^Cpg_recvlogical: unexpected termination of replication stream: ubuntu@ip-192-168-170-204:~$ cat change.txt
{"change":[{"kind":"delete","schema":"goldsky_api","table":"Webhook","oldkeys":{"keynames":["id"],"keytypes":["text"],"keyvalues":["webhook_clffq45rf0eyj3ss5c1hjezo8"]}}]}
ubuntu@ip-192-168-170-204:~$ cat change.txt | psql "postgresql://root:<redacted>@graph-node-db-2.cpyibfvmddkk.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com/goldsky"
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "{"
LINE 1: {"change":[{"kind":"delete","schema":"goldsky_api","table":"...
        ^
```

I've tried changing the plugin type to `pgoutput` which resulted in the following error:

```
client sent proto_version=0 but we only support protocol 1 or higher
```

I've tried using the `text_decoder` output which also had syntax errors during psql ingestion:

```
ubuntu@ip-192-168-170-204:~$ cat change.txt | psql "postgresql://root:<redacted>@graph-node-db-2.cpyibfvmddkk.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com/goldsky" -a -b -e
BEGIN 1022180790
table goldsky_api."Webhook": DELETE: id[text]:'webhook_clffr35r30flm3ss5h6e33mm0'
COMMIT 1022180790
BEGIN 1022180925
table goldsky_api."Webhook": INSERT: id[text]:'webhook_clffr4n0t0fn23sqv6g2f62so' name[text]:'main' project_id[text]:'project_cl6whd3a6000k0ixjfp9t9at5' subgraph_deployment_id[text]:'sgd_cle4aoyna00o63svl90yf1h9z' created_at[timestamp with time zone]:'2023-03-19 18:48:59.803+00'
COMMIT 1022180925
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "1022180790"
LINE 1: BEGIN 1022180790
```

How can I get `psql` to understand and apply the changes that `pg_recvlogical` sees when subscribing to a replication slot? Is there a way to use unix pipes to achieve this?

Comment: It's not SQL, so I'm not sure why you're trying to use it with psql. Can you not do normal logical replication between the two different Amazon services?

Comment: I have premium support and when I spoke with the DMS team they suggested that I should use postgres native tooling because their DMS service doesn't not take care of foreign keys, secondary indexes and other such things which aren't required for successful data migration.

Comment: Are you aware of another tool I can use to do logical replication? I'm all ears for any solution!

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/logical-replication.html